# Navbar en bootstrap, mover hacia abajo cuando se despliegue el menú

Tags: html, bootstrap

He hecho un `navbar reponsive` con `bootstrap` sencillo, el cual, al no entrar todos los `nav-links` en la pantalla se crea un menú desplegable.

Vale hasta ahí todo bien. El problema es que a la hora de usar el menú, este se despliega encima de mi `header` en vez de mandarlo para debajo, es decir, los `nav-links` se despliegan encima de la foto del `header`.

Lo que quiero es que la imagen se mueva hacia abajo cuando se despliegue el menú.

[image: Este es el fallo]

---

Este seria el codigo de la imagen. Siento el despieste

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light container sticky-top" style="height: 8vh;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://d1yjjnpx0p53s8.cloudfront.net/styles/logo-thumbnail/s3/092015/vitaldent.png?itok=wP8_B1Lc" alt="logo" style="width: 18vh;"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#">
          <h5 class="text-primary">Donde estamos</h5>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#">
          <h5 class="text-primary">Cita previa</h5>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img width="100%" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/30/08/08/business-3362081_1280.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Se me ocurre que al momento de mostrar el menú cresca tu div para que ocupe el espacio requerido y así tu imagen se recorra !

Comment: No se puede inferir muy bien porque no está el código (si puedes ponerlo, se agradecería), pero necesito preguntarlo: ¿Tu barra de navegación está fija? (o sea, si ella tiene la clase `navbar-fixed-top` en BS3, o `fixed-top` en BS4)

Comment: Siento lo del codigo, no me di cuenta ;(

Comment: tal vez esto te ayude un poco https://styde.net/barra-de-navegacion-navbar-transparente-con-bootstrap-y-css/

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo, fijate que seguramente el navbar está dentro de un contenedor donde le asignaste un height, borrale esa declaración y cuando despliegues el dicho navbar todo crecerá uniformemente y no colapsará hacia arriba

Answer (score 2):

si estas usando Boostrap deberias usar `collapse`para mostrar contenido oculto en forma de acordeón (esto desplaza los divs hacia abajo, que es lo que quieres hacer), es fácil de usar y de configurar, por ejemplo:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Mostarar/Ocultar</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
 Algún Texto
</div>
```

Toda la documentacion la encuentras directamente el la documentacion de boostrap, ahi mismo hay muchos ejemplos:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0):

como previamente te han comentado puedes usar un evento collapse en bootstrap. Yo intenté otra forma combinando bootstrap y estilos basándome en el proyecto siguiente: https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/hmade/ cantado sería de la siguiente manera, tienes que agregar las clases, a prestar atención:

```
.push-wrap {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.show-nav .push-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
}
```

El evento:

```
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
     return false;
  });

});


// Toggle with hitting of ESC
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
   $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
  }
});
```

Siguiendo mi forma obtendríamos un resultado parecido al tuyo.

```js
// Normal Clicks
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
     return false;
  });
  
});


// Toggle with hitting of ESC
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 27) {
   $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.site-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.push-wrap {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.show-nav .push-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 240px);
    transform: translate(0, 240px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 240px, 0);
}

a {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
nav {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1500px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}
article h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 30px;
}
article p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
article a.toggle-nav {
  position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(68, 71, 87);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

i {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrap">
  <nav class=" bg-light container-fluid sticky-top">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">¿Dónde estamos?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tratamiento</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Previa cita</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="push-wrap">
    <article>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VITALDENT</a>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-nav">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </nav>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img
              width="100%" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/30/08/08/business-3362081_1280.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.